# How to convert fan switch to new light switch?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I just moved into a new house.  In the bedrooms there is a pre-installed light fixture that is pre-wired to be converted into a ceiling fan. There is already dual gang switch, a dimmer for the light and the second one for the fan switch.  Since there is no fan, that fan switch is obviously serving no function right now.  I'm assuming that the fan switch has the red wire attached with the other end of the red wire likely capped within the light fixture.  I would like to install some recessed ceiling lights into the bedroom and have them on a separate switch from the already installed light fixture.  The proper way to do this install is to run new romex wire from the fan switch, cap that red wire, and use that to feed the new recessed lights.  However I know that the red wire is a hot wire.  Is there SAFE way of using that red wire that was meant for the fan and use it to power the new recessed lights instead?  If so, what would be the proper way to wire this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the existing box that supports the bedroom light as  a junction box.  Run a 14-2 from there, black to red and white to white, all grounds together. The other end of this can now be used for the new lights in the bed room. Good luck.